# Rails Devise Extra User Signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am new to rails.
Using rails 4 and devise. I am attempting to use the single user model with a class variable called role, which would determine if the user was a customer or a admin.

I have created a copy of the /views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
to: /views/devise/registrations/sign_up2.html.erb

and then in my routes.rb added:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "users/sign_up2"=> "devise/registrations#sign_up2", :as => "sign_up2"
end
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

I have a customer registration controller (at controllers/users/registration_controller.rb)

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 include ApplicationHelper

 def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :profile_name, :role, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all (especially if you're new to Rails): Stick to the conventions, unless you really have to change them.
I cannot see, why sign_up needs to be renamed.

Second: You try to route to action `sign_up2` of controller `Devise::RegistrationsController`, but that controller does not have a method `sign_up2`.
Perhaps you wanted to route to your own Controller `Users::RegistrationsController`, than your route looks like:

```
device_scope :user do
  get "users/sing_up2" => "users/registrations#sign_up2", as: "sign_up2"
end
```

But your own controller has no action "sign_up2" either.

Third: (and that's the error you see)
the view you copied starts with

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

but `resource` was not set. In `Devise::RegistrationsController` the action `new` (that is where `sign_up` routes to in standard `devise`) starts with

```
build_resource({})
```

You need something similar in your controllers `sing_up2` method.